# Django exclude both fields blank

Tags: python, django

I need to do an exclude on a django query to exclude records where both fields are blank but include if there is one or the other or both.

My model looks like

```
class Example(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
```

right now I am writing the query as

```
Example.objects.filter(general_query).exclude(title=u'').exclude(name=u'')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, simply put 2 conditions together under the same `exclude()`:

```
Example.objects.filter(general_query).exclude(title=u'', name=u'')
```

Only both conditions are met will be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

Use Q objects

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
Example.objects.filter(general_query).exclude(Q(title='') & Q(name=''))
```

Comment: I accepted the other because its simpler and I understand it... but thanks for the link I'll read through it when I get a chance!

Comment: Whoops. The Q's are wholly unnecessary.